# Gateways and Pfsense

Tags: routing, pfsense

I have a question regarding pfsense and routing in general.

I have a laptop that is connected to ISP router, the second laptop runs pfsense and few more laptops are connected to it via a switch.

```
isp router network is: 192.168.1.0/24

pfsense eth0: 192.168.1.100/24
pfsense eth0 gateway: 192.168.1.1 (isp router)
pfsense eth2: 192.168.2.1/24

laptop 1: 192.168.1.36/24
gateway for laptop 1: 192.168.1.1 (isp router)

laptop 2: 192.168.2.2
gateway for laptop 2: 192.168.2.1 (pfsense)
```

So the problem is, I would like to ping my hosts behind pfsense. however, it doesn't work unless I specify pfsense machine as a gateway for laptop 1.

Question: is there any way to have multiple gateways on my machine? why my isp router can't find its path to 192.168.2.0/24 network. I am new to networking so can't wrap my head around it just yet. big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ISP router can't find a route to `192.168.2.0/24` because it doesn't know about it. Routing discovery is not automatic, even though it sometimes seems like it.

Your ISPs router should hopefully have the ability to add a static route. Add a route for `192.168.2.0/24` with a next-hop of `192.168.1.100`

That'll get packets into your pfsense box. Then you'll just need firewall rules to allow the packets from the two subnets to flow together.